# How to parse Json in java with json having an additional part?

Tags: java, json

I have the following JSON text that I need to parse to get symbol, name.

What is the required code?

```
YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback(
    {"ResultSet":
    {"Query":
    "yhoo",
    "Result":[
    {"symbol":"YHOO","name":"Yahoo!Inc.",
    "exch":"NMS","type":"S","exchDisp":"NASDAQ","typeDisp":"Equity"},
    {"symbol":"YHOO.MX","name":"Yahoo!Inc.",
    "exch":"MEX","type":"S","exchDisp":"Mexico","typeDisp":"Equity" }]}})
```

i think YAHOO.finance... part is causing some issue.

Comment: Well yes, that isn't JSON. Where are you getting it from, and can you get just the JSON instead? If not, you could probably chop everything before and including the first `(`, and remove the trailing `)` too

Answer (score 0):

I dont know, what exactly is "YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback". However inside that function it is valid JSON. To get it, simple remove it, for example by something like this this :

```
yourText.substring(yourText.indexOf(), yourText.length - 2 );
```

(the code is not checked, probably there can be issue with +1 or -1 character at index, just test it)

To Parse it, use Jackson (just google it). It is very simple - you create object, which represent object in JSON and it automatically parse it from String to Java Object (also it can automatically ignore nonexisting field = you dont have to crate 1:1 object, only the part you are interested int).